# How to hide the implementation class using Interface or Abstaract class

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

I have this scenario with me. there would be two flavours of project build,

1. Normal Build
2. Developer Build.

In case of a developer build i will require to compile few more packages and include them in the build structure.

There is common file `MainClass` in this case,

```
Mainclass {
     if(devFeature){
        CommonInterface int = new DeveloperFile();
         ........ other logic ......
     }else{
         CommonInterface int = new NormalFile();
         ........ other logic ......
     }
}
```

as above `MainClass` is a CommonResource the jar holding `DeveloperFile` is referenced only during the Dev build. **But during a normal build, this would lead to compilation error.**

How can i solve this ? any design pattern in specific ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [reflection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/) to instantiate your classes.

Here is a basic example, The `concreteClass` variable can be read from a file or passed as a parameter to the main method:

```
String concreteClass = ...
CommonInterface instance = Class.forName(concreteClass).newInstance();
...
```

---

Or better, you can use a framework that use reflection behind the scenes for you. As an example [Spring](https://spring.io/) do exactly that.

In this case using a concrete class or another one needs only a modification in a configuration file.

Answer (score 2):

[Inversion of Control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control) is probably the most appropriate pattern here (in Java, one framework that does this is Spring, another popular is the JEE's EJB), since what you essentially need is for the environment to tell your `MainClass` which class to use.

Another pattern you could use is the [Service Locator pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service_locator_pattern). You can look at how the JDBC drivers are located - in versions prior to JDBC4, it basically works like this:

- You have a *registry* class that keeps information on what implementation of `CommonInterface` is available
- The concrete implementations of the interface have a static initializer that registers the class with the *registry*
- You give your `MainClass` the *name* of the implementation to use (as a `String`, so no compile-time dependency is created)
- The `MainClass` calls `Class.forName(implName)`, this loads the class and invokes the static initializer, registering the implementation
- Then the `MainClass` uses the *registry* as a *factory*, calling something like `registry.getCommonInterface()`

And JDBC4 uses Java's built-in [Service provider](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jar/jar.html#Service%20Provider) mechanism, which you could probably use as well.

Answer (score -2):

Something simple: use a Factory. All you really need is to have two versions of `CommonInterfaceFactory`, one that creates instances of `DeveloperFile` and another that creates instances of `NormalFile`. Make sure the first is included in your developer build and the second in your normal build.

```
CommonInterface int1 = CommonInterfaceFactory.makeCommonInterfaceInstance();
```

Comment: So you suggest having two different classes that share the same name? Ewww. Why bother with the factory then and not use two different `CommonInterface` implementations both with the same name?

Comment: "Ewww"? LOL. Not exactly a pithy criticism, but gets your point across.

Comment: But seriously, sure, why not? You could definitely have two different implementations with the same name. This is quite common when supplying platform-specific implementations for JNI code.

Comment: Not exactly formally correct, I know. Sorry for that. Some points as to why not - 1) Risk of developer getting confused and editing the wrong class (since they cannot make sure by just looking at the file/class name) 2) If customer sends you a stacktrace, which version of the class does it relate to? You'll have to find it in your documentation and hope it's true. 3) Problems communicating inside your team - "That class? Which version?" 4) If it ever happens that you'll need both versions in the same application, you're in trouble.

Comment: Reasonable criticisms, but not fatal. 1-3 can be addressed simply by making the class a thin wrapper around another, uniquely named class. And #4 contradicts the basic premise of the question, that these are mutually exclusive.